# How to disable squared background of WPF UI designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I want to change the background of WPF UI designer and it is simple to change the color of the background, but after I change the color of the background, the look of the designer becomes horrible because of squares.
How to disable squared background?

[image]

Comment: what squares ? can you post a snapshot

Comment: yikes ... I am  dizzy now..

Comment: I have no idea whats happenin in here, you can try this extension and see if you  can modify color properly ? ..... https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors, select **XAML UI Designer** and set Item foreground and Item background to the same color.

Comment: It works, but what then those colors mean? I mean, VS shows that when you make these colors the same you won't see the text...

Comment: Yes, the sample in the settings window is misleading. It should show the squared background instead of text.